# Applying for a job with my overall GPA or within my major?

Tags: hiring-process, applications

I started out at my school as an mechanical engineering major, but I didn't do well and quickly realized it wasn't for me. I switched majors to computer science/mathematics and have done quite well. My overall GPA is about 3.3 but if you discount all the bad grades I got from my old engineering major it goes up to a 3.6. I feel like reporting a 3.3 is selling myself a bit short as almost all of my bad grades are in an area of study I'm not even remotely involved in, but I also feel like putting the 3.6 down without comment seems very misleading. What should I do when applying to a job?

Comment: If you want to give a GPA, put the final GPA listed on your transcript, but if it's a 3.3, you probably shouldn't mention it unless they ask.

Comment: @AffableAmbler this is in reference to jobs I'm applying for directly out of college, where often the most important factor can be GPA.

Comment: You already know the answer, you only asked the question hoping you were wrong I think.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere unless its for a job inventing subsets... :)

Comment: @JoeStrazzere A major GPA isn't an "invented subset". My transcripts always listed an overall GPA and a field-of-study GPA.

Comment: As pointed out by JoeStrazzere, the title "overall GPA or within my major" is not the same as what you describe in your question. "If you discount all the bad grades I got ..." should be clarified. If you report a major GPA it should ideally be the same as on your transcript. E.g. Transcript says: "Major GPA: 1.2345" Your CV says: "Major GPA: 1.2345". That way I can easily understand where the information comes from.

Comment: I feel like I need to clarify just a little bit. I report my major GPAs exactly as Brandin said; I am not picking and choosing which grades to include and which not. The job I'm applying for is quite competitive and is aimed at new graduates... a sort of "externship". I do have relevant work experience, and plenty of qualifications that I believe put me above most of the applicants, but because it is aimed at new graduates, they seem to be filtering based on GPA. All that being said, I'm starting to lean towards what seems to be the prevailing opinion so far, but I'll let the discussion run

Comment: Is "Major GPA" an official metric provided by your school or is it something you calculated yourself? I ask because I've never heard of this before.  Also, I'm not sure that it's fair to discount everything that's not directly related to your major.  If you got an A in every programming class but you failed English, as an employer, I'd like to know about that.

Comment: @AffableAmbler It's not written directly on the transcript but they have an official tool that shows you it. Also it should be mentioned that it does include gen-ed classes like English, but does not include classes that my employer would likely not care about, like "Physics 2: Electromagnetism"

Comment: Gotcha. In that case, I think it should be okay.

Answer (score 2):

You should use your overall GPA or qualify that you were using your major GPA, otherwise you will be perceived as having tried to deceive them.

A 3.6 is not so much better than a 3.3 that I would take the risk.  If you are proud of the 3.6 then you could include it also.  But it is unlikely that any job that 3.6 would qualify for, a 3.3 is not going to qualify for. So to me I would not bother calling attention to it.  If your GPA is not exceptional(4.0) then it doesn't really matter its either good enough or its not.

If you had a much lower GPA, it might be worth including the major GPA just to off set any negative impression that might have caused.

Comment: I find your statement that a 3.6 is not so much better than a 3.3 rather dubious. It's the difference (at my university) between graduating without honors and graduating Cum Laude

Comment: @bendl - I think you attach more significance to that than there really is.  and in a world where they care about that difference your 3.6 is on the wrong side.

Comment: For a job immediately out of college I'm not sure how else they're supposed to judge graduates' qualifications. Most don't have experience so GPA and what school you're coming from are often the only things to pick interviews from. Of course I'd love to be proven wrong but I just don't know what else they could be looking at

Comment: @bendl - They are seperated into the exceptional (4.0 overall) and everyone else.  In the real world if its not perfect its just acceptable.  there is nothing wrong with being acceptable. I am, but its the reality.

Comment: I think this answer is missing mention that in the real world, the GPA doesn't really matter unless it was exceedingly exceptional. A first employer won't care that you were able to study well, they will care about what kind of person you are and how quickly you can be turned into a productive employee.

Answer (score 1):

> I feel like reporting a 3.3 is selling myself a bit short as almost
>   all of my bad grades are in an area of study I'm not even remotely
>   involved in, but I also feel like putting the 3.6 down without comment
>   seems very misleading. What should I do when applying to a job?

Since the application in question requires that you fill in the field with a single value, you must enter 3.3.

You can explain why 3.3 doesn't adequately convey your abilities in a cover letter and during your interviews.

In your resume you can put anything you like. Some folks with less than stellar GPAs like to include only their "major GPA". If you take that route, make sure it's properly labeled.

You could choose to include "GPA discounting all the bad grades you got from your old engineering major", but that would be rather awkward to explain in a resume and might come across as misleading.

If, as you have expressed, a potential employer will judge you strongly on your GPA, then you simply need to be prepared to explain your 3.3 and your college experiences as best you can. Emphasize what you learned about yourself when you changed majors and how your later years showed vast improvement. Most companies relying that much on GPA will want to look at your transcript and will understand what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick to your major GPA- Computer Science / Mathematics. Most often, employers use GPA **as one factor among several** to evaluate your aptitude for the position. Assuming you will be applying for technical jobs in CS, your major GPA would be most relevant to what you will be doing on the job, and better allow your prospective employer to evaluate your abilities.

A 3.30 GPA is actually decent and most employers should not have an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. This is what I did on my resume:

- Cumulative GPA X
- Major 1: Y
- Major 2: Z
- Major 3: A

Major GPA was calculated based on degree requirements for the major alone.

Comment: I do a similar thing on my resume. The application that brought me to ask this question, however, asked for my GPA in a write-in field outside of my resume. My question is more geared towards that scenario. I have provided a resume, but I would prefer it get read before it's tossed aside as being below the standards

Comment: If their hard cut off is 3.5 (yours is 3.3) then it is a hard cut-off. Another avenue is to write a letter to the hiring manager/HR/recruiter indicating that despite your 0.2 below the mark, you have qualities that are a great fit for the role. In other words, appeal to one's sense of emotion rather than logic.